# Custom date format in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch, jodatime

I am trying to format a date field in elastic-search using the joda-time library formats. I want to achieve the format `"Mon Sep 18 17:12:37 IST 2017"`.First I used the following code:

```
"alarm_timestamp": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "EEE MMM d H:m:s zzz YYYY"
}
```

It did not work. Later, I read the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360579/custom-date-format-in-elasticsearch-mapping). So, I changed the code:

```
"alarm_timestamp": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "E MMM d H:m:s z Y"
}
```

In both cases, mapping was successfully created. But, It gave error when I tried to index data.

The error it gives is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
              "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
              "reason": "failed to parse [alarm_timestamp]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse [alarm_timestamp]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Invalid format: \"Mon Sep 18 17:12:37 IST 2017\" is malformed at \"IST 2017\""
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Any suggestion(s)?

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val: I use elasticsearch-5.6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) for `format`:

> Completely customizable date formats are supported. The syntax for
>   these is explained in the Joda docs.

The [Joda docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) says about `z`:

> Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

The problem is that these abbreviations like `IST` for timezones can be ambiguous.

The [Wikipedia Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) page says the following:

> **Abbreviations**
>   Time zones
>   are often represented by alphabetic abbreviations such as "EST",
>   "WST", and "CST", but **these are not part of the international time and
>   date standard ISO 8601 and their use as sole designator for a time
>   zone is discouraged**. Such designations can be ambiguous; for example,
>   "ECT" could be interpreted as "Eastern Caribbean Time" (UTC−4h),
>   "Ecuador Time" (UTC−5h), or "European Central Time" (UTC+1h).

So you will see that some abbreviations will work and some will not. It is encouraged not to use these abbreviations. Instead use one of the following:

- `E MMM d H:m:s Z Y` and index as `Mon Sep 18 17:12:37 +02:00 2017`
- `E MMM d H:m:s ZZZ Y` and index as `Mon Sep 18 17:12:37 Europe/Istanbul 2017`

Here is a list of [Available Time Zones](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) for Joda.